# Prostitute could be a joke?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am learning English at a language school in Korea. Today's topic was about overtime and our teacher who is American asked me how many hours I work per week. 
I said I cannot concentrate in the morning, so I  usually work from noon to midnight.
And the teacher asked me "Are you a prostitute? "
I know what a prostitute means. But I don't know if I can take that as a joke or harassment. Anyway I really don't feel good.

Comment: Prostitution, traditionally, has been night-time work. So yes, he was jokingly asking "*What job do you have that you must work all night?*". Being an American, I can tell you we are known for sarcastic and crude humor, and it doesn't always go over well abroad. In Japan, for example, sometimes the subtitles on American films have to explicitly note *this is a joke*.

Comment: It was most likely a joke, but one in poor taste.  It's harrassment, if you feel harrassed.

Comment: It was almost certainly a joke, but a very poor one.  If it bothers you you should either confront the teacher or discuss it with his superior.

Comment: Since the teacher is not headlining at the Don Rickles Room on the Las Vegas Strip—or doing stand-up comedy during open-mic night at the Laff Lounge in Lodi, California—he shouldn't be suggesting (even as a joke) that if a student works late it may be because she's a prostitute. The teacher's "just a joke" off-the-cuff innuendo would not be acceptable in U.S. schools either, for the very reason you give: it can leave a student feeling uneasy, insulted, hit on, or simply "not good." So it's not a matter of cultural difference between U.S. and Korean senses of humor; it's inappropriate behavior.

Comment: @DanBron - Noon to midnight is not suggestive of that kind of work, and that remark is not close to funny or appropriate, even for the worst American. Not to belabor the point too much, hospital shift work (middle shift) is 3 to 11. If someone asked a nurse if she was a prostitute when she informed him of her shift, I would hope they got a "very rude awakening".

Comment: I think you should report this to the management. Not only is it inappropriate, it is something that can never be uttered by a teacher. I would never tolerate such behavior in any class.

Comment: Presumably the language course is a private one, by that I mean you are paying the institution good money. Before taking any course of action though, check that your classmates heard this "punchline" and whether they understood it was said as a joke, and/or if they too felt uncomfortable. You don't want to find yourself in the situation where it's your word against this teacher. Afterwards, ask to meet the director of studies, or the management, and relate this disturbing episode to them. I'm surprised however that an American would say such a thing.

Comment: How old is the guy by the way? Is he terribly young? If he's straight out of college then it's a blunder, albeit a colossal one, but you might decide to let it pass. You could have a word with him in private and ask for an apology—that might help.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - He's over 50. I don't want to talk to him. It's like... I don't want to see his face. I'm considering that I should move to another class.

Comment: In that case, be brave and report him immediately. If the guy's creeping you out, you're probably not the first one. The school needs to know about the teacher's behaviour, they will probably suggest moving you to a different class.That is a good idea, it will also send a clear message to the teacher.

Comment: Aside.  Taking advice from strangers concerning a matter like this is absurd. Use your friends, who know you. Your relationship is paramount here.  Definitive answers to do this or that are typically given by those predisposed.  Take suggestions and comments as  such and think for yourself.   Scripted responses have reduced us to processes.  Why is this question even here?

Comment: @user116032 - As I said, I am learning English and not familiar with American culture and language. My classmates are not so different than me. I wanted to know how the teacher's comment is felt to native English speakers. Sorry if this is a wrong place to post but I couldn't find any place better.

Comment: @user116032 the ironic thing is though, you are also a complete stranger and yet you feel bound to tell her not to take advice from strangers, which is in itself a piece of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with words is that you can look for the meaning in a dictionary, but as soon as you put it in a sentence the meaning changes, coloured by the words around it and the situation it is used in.

This means that the only answer to your question is "maybe..."

If your teacher was laughing when he said it, it was probably intended as a joke, but that doesn't mean you have to accept it as one. I would call it '[a joke in bad taste](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+bad+taste)' and you are justified in feeling bad about it.

Comment: The teacher is a guy. Not she.

Comment: Answer amended...

Answer (score 0):

i guess it was a joke but not funny at all and absolutely tacky. What English school do you go to in Korea? is it actually school or 'Hak won?

Comment: Did you not read the comments? Did you not read the answer posted? Asking the user to say "which" school she attends is also counter-productive, and potentially risky. The OP needs to remain anonymous in cases such as these.